# PayPal buy button custom coding.

Tags: button

I am building an e-commerce website and have hit my final hurdle with the site. Setting up the pay structure is the only thing remaining for me to be able to launch the site.

What I would like to do (which may not be possible) is for my users to be able to post items for sale and then another registered user be able to purchase that item directly with a PayPal transaction. I have found this code which adds a buy button to the ad pages:

```
add_action("adverts_tpl_single_bottom", "paypal_adverts_tpl_single_bottom", 
1000);
function paypal_adverts_tpl_single_bottom( $post_id ) {
$post = get_post( $post_id );
?>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR EMAIL HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="BM">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post-
>post_title) ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta( 
$post_id, "adverts_price", true)) ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay 
online!">
<img alt="" border="0" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" 
height="1">
</form>

<?php
}
```

This is great and does function, however this sends the payment to my website rather than the user who is selling the item. I would need the pay button to pull the email address of the user who posted the ad (this should be embedded in the very page that the pay button sits) and have the payment go to them instead of the site. The pay button already sends the money from whatever user clicks the pay button (they must be logged in to pay). This seems like it is actually possible, but the next part (the actual challenge) does not.

The real hard part is that I would like to take a 3 dollars fee per transaction that goes through the site. I originally thought that if I took the payment from the buyer to my website, I could then auto-generate a second payment to the seller minus the 3 dollar fee. However, if I do this and there is an issue with the transaction and the buyer or seller needs to open a dispute, it will be my websites email address listed in the PayPal system and I will be stuck in the middle of the dispute. I need the payment to go from the buyer directly to the seller with my site somehow collecting a fee.

I have seen another website that seems to accomplish this: swappa.com

I hope that someone with coding knowledge will be able to point me in the right direction here as this is all I need to launch the site. Thank you for reading.